# Python - replace / by \\ in path to open file in windows10

Tags: python, path, slash

I have a list with the path of some images:

> `Image_path_/ = os.path.join(str(folder_with_images))`
>   `Image_path_/`
>
> > `"('C:/Users/A/Desktop/image.tif',)"`

To open the image.tif in [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) on windows 10, I need the path of the image like:
"C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\image.tif"

I want an automatic process. While running the script, a Macros.txt is overwritten and it is opened later with ImageJ
First, I need to save the path above as str in a var:
Image_path_\\ = "C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\image.tif"

Then, the Macros.txt is overwriten. In the second line below the var Image_path_\ should be inserted

> `F = open(r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\Macros.txt",'w')`
>   `F.write('open(' +  Image_path_\\\ + ')';\n')   #equal to : F.write('open(C:\\\Users\\\A\\\Desktop\\\image.tif);\n')`
>   `F.close()`

The problem is that I cannot find the way to write \\ with python.
How can I replace / by \\ in order to assign it in a variable as str?

Comment: What's the original value of `folder_with_images`? Currently, you aren't giving `os.path.join` anything to do: it joins multiple strings; it does not replace one path separator with another.

Comment: did you try `path.replace('/', '\\')`?

Comment: @MaxxikCZ I wouldn't recommend that, because strictly speaking, `/` could be part of a folder name, not a separator.

Comment: @chepner isn't `/` a part of a group of chars blocked by windows? also... The path is separated with forward slashes. Meaning any forward slash is clearly a path separator

Comment: Ah, my mistake. `/` is reserved (though for what, I'm not sure. Related to command-line switches, maybe?)

Comment: Folder_with_images is only the list where the path of the images is contained.

Comment: I tried with path.replace('/','\\'). But it does not work. I need a string in the var. Image_path_\\ to write in the Macros.txt. It seems python does not accept a var. as 'C\\.....' from a windows path

Answer (score 0):

I could solved with a small modification of what @Maxxik CZ suggested.

> path_str = str(path)
>   path_file = path_str.replace('\\', '\\\\')

with this I can write the .txt file and insert the path+name if image

> F.write("open('" + path_file + '\\\\denoised_' + name_image + "');\n")